# Segmentation fault while implementing stack as an array

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, stack

This is a menu-driven program that carries out basic stack operations using arrays in the C programming language. The functions that are performed are push, pop, peep,isempty and isfull.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


struct stack
{
    long int top;
    long int size;
    char* key;
};


int is_empty(struct stack *s)  //check if its empty
{
    if(s->top==-1)
    {
            return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
int is_full(struct stack *s)  //check if its full
{
    if (s->top ==s->size-1)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}


void push(struct stack *s, char x)  //pushes into stack
{
int check;
check = is_full(s);
if(check==-1)
{
    printf("-1\n");
   
}
else
{
s->top = s->top+1;
s->key[s->top]=x;
}
}

 
void pop(struct stack *s)   //deletes the last element
{
int check;
check = is_empty(s);
if(check==-1)
{
    printf("-1\n");
    
    
}
else
{
char k;
k = s->key[s->top];
printf("%c\n",k);
s->top--;
}
}

void peep(struct stack *s)  //prints the last element without deleting
{   int check;
char k;
    check = is_empty(s);
    if (check == -1)
    {
        printf("-1\n");
    }
    else
    {
            k = s->key[s->top];
           printf("%c \n",k);
    }    
}

int main()
{


    char ch;
    char x;
    long int n;
    struct stack *s;
    scanf("%ld ", &n);
    s->size = n;  //initialise the size 
    s->top = -1;  //setting as -1 base case
    s->key= (char *)malloc(n*sizeof(char));  //dynamic allocation of keys
    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%c ",&ch);
        switch(ch)
        {
        case 'i':
                scanf("%c ",&x);
                push(s,x);
                break;
        case 'd':pop(s);
                break;
        case 'p':peep(s);
                break;
        case 't':exit(0); //termination case
    }  
}
return 0;
}
```

This is a C program that is working for me in some online compilers but in VScode and other compilers, it's showing a segmentation fault without any output. This is an implementation of stack using arrays. Is it a problem with any of the scanf functions?

Comment: In the `main` function you have the pointer variable `s`, but *where does it point?*

Comment: On an unrelated note, don't use trailing spaces in `scanf` formatting strings. That could lead to problems in many cases (like having to give extra input so `scanf` knows when the spaces ends). To skip white-space when reading characters, use *leading* space instead. I.e. change `"%c "` to `" %c"` (and remove the space from the numeric input).

Comment: ok, i got it should I dynamically initialise the struct pointer 's' with the value of the size?

Comment: No need for dynamic allocation, use a plain structure object, `strut stack s;` and then pass pointers to it using the address-of (or pointer-to) operator `&`, like `&s`.

Comment: so i should change the function as:  push(&s,x)? with structure as plain variable s

Comment: It's both a tiny thing and not: properly formatted code is so much easier to work with. Please try keeping your code formatted nicely. If you don't have an IDE that does it for you, it's not difficult to maintain manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created a pointer variable `s` and then access the `size` field on that struct.

```
    struct stack *s;
    scanf("%ld ", &n);
    s->size = n;  //initialise the size
```

Except `s` doesn't actually point to anything at this point. You need to either statically or dynamically allocate memory for that struct.

```
struct stack s;
```

Or:

```
struct stack *s = malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
```